# Powerbuilder 12.5.2 Classic .NET Web Service error with Amazon SQS WSDL

Tags: amazon-web-services, wsdl, powerbuilder

I get the error below when I try to access the Amazon SQS WSDL:

http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/QueueService.wsdl

Cannot access the WSDL or the WSDL file is invalid.

I believe I have .NET 4 SDK installed and I have tried downloading the WSDL file to a local drive and pointing the proxy wizard to it. Still the same error.

Can someone try to use it and let me know your outcomes?

Comment: I can access the URL posted. Are you behind a corporate proxy?

Comment: We are behind a corporate proxy but the call is via port 80 which is allowed and I can access the wsdl via IE. Are you trying it via PB?

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand the question fully. No, I'm not trying it via PB. Corporate proxies are evil though, so if possible I would ask the proxy admin if there is any rule that blocks HTTP traffic coming from non-browser applications.

Comment: No worries. I have just tried it through a open network and I get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the .Net WSDL utility directly on the WSDL.  That utility reports back error information.  It's also what PowerBuilder is calling under the covers, but is not sharing the error information back to you.

When I do that, I get this result:

Error: Unable to import binding 'SimpleQueueServicePostBinding' from namespace '
http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/'.
  - The operation 'GetQueueUrl' on portType 'SimpleQueueServicePortType' from na
mespace 'http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/' had the following syntax error:
  The operation has no matching binding. Check if the operation, input and 
output names in the Binding section match with the corresponding names in the PortType section.

It looks like it might be a problem with the format of the WSDL.  Not the first time that's happened, I've had to edit one of their other WSDL files by hand to correct an error in it.

If you choose to do that, you can download the file to your local machine, make the edits, and then run the PB proxy tool against the local file.